# Two (oracle) turing machines producing the same language

Tags: reductions

I need to solve the question if two given oracle turing machines M$_{1}$ and M$_{2}$ have the same language, so T(M$_{1}$) = T(M$_{1}$). An oracle turing machine  can use such an oracle for deciding if a normal turing machine will stop on an empty tape. It should be reduced to equivalence problem between two normal turing machines but I can't imagine how  that should work. I mean  the equivalence itself is reduced to the holding problem with empty tape.
Could someone provide some help or advice how to solve this?

Comment: What is $T(M_1)$?

Comment: Did you mean $T(M_1) = T(M_2)$ ? (also not sure what is $T(M)$)